# How to find if a value exists in a range and print "FOUND" or "MISSING" in a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to perform a function similar to the function in Excel fount below:

```
IF(COUNTIF(RANGE, CRITERIA), "FOUND", "MISSING")
```

I want to print a new column in my dataframe with found or missing. I understand in R that I can use %in% for example:

```
A$C %in C$B
```

To find if the values in column C of the A dataframe exist in the values in column B of the C datafame. However, I do not know how to subset said results with a conditional function to print found or missing to a new column in the correct row.

Here is an example of the dataframes:

```
A <- data.frame("C" = c(3,5,9,21,25), "D" = 1:5)
C <- data.frame("B" = c(3,6,21,22,8) , "F" = 10:14)

A$C %in% C$B

A[A$C %in% C$B,]
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the limited information:

```
lookup_list <- c(1:3)

x <- c('a','b','c')
y <- c(10, 3, 5)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

x  y
1 a 10
2 b  3
3 c  5

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(status = case_when(
    y %in% lookup_list ~ 'FOUND',
    !y %in% lookup_list ~ 'MISSING'
  ))

x  y  status
1 a 10 MISSING
2 b  3   FOUND
3 c  5 MISSING
```

Comment: This worked great. In my next question I will add an example to make things easier. Thank you for your time.